# Flutter app, Theme of AppBar deprecated title, used headline6 but not work

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, title, appbar

When using appBarTheme with headline6 upgraded version title was not visible.

```
appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
              color: AppStyles.naturalBlackColor,
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              elevation: 0,
              textTheme: TextTheme(
                  headline6: TextStyle(
                      color: AppStyles.naturalBlackColor,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in material app

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        appBarTheme:  Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
              color: Colors.yellow,//your color
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              elevation: 0,
              textTheme:const TextTheme(
                  headline6: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,//your color
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
            )
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```